# Shortening recursive logic in unique list generation

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I would like to combine the two funcs below into one much shorter one.

`random_strs` generates a list of `n` unique strings, each of length `length`, pulling from whatever `letters` container is specified.  `nonunique_random_strs` is just a helper called within.  The logic is to check the number of unique elements against `n`, then to add elements and repeat this process until the two are equal.

```
import numpy as np

def nonunique_random_strs(length, n, letters):
    strs = np.random.choice(letters, size=(n, length)).tolist()
    strs = [''.join(inner) for inner in strs]
    return strs

def random_strs(length, n, letters):
    strs = list(set(nonunique_random_strs(length, n, letters)))
    to_add = n - len(strs)
    while to_add > 0:
        added = nonunique_random_strs(length=length, n=to_add, letters=letters)
        strs.extend(added)
        strs = list(set(strs))
        to_add = n - len(strs)
    return strs

print(random_strs(length=2, n=5, letters=list('abcde')))
# ['cb', 'ce', 'dc', 'db', 'ba']
```

So it's functional, but I'd like to reference `random_strs` within itself and am having trouble building that.

Comment: Maybe nest the function?

Comment: Is your goal here "learn about recursion"? Because if not, I think you could get the same result by replacing the above with `print(random.sample(list(itertools.combinations('abcde', 2)), 5))`.

Comment: @BradSolomon list of strings `random.sample([a + b for a,b in itertools.combinations('abcde', 2)], 5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This became a lot easier with `itertools` and using standard `random` rather than `np.random`:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement
import random
import string

def random_strs(length, n):
    letters = string.ascii_uppercase
    res = random.sample(list(combinations_with_replacement(letters, 
                                                           length)), n)
    res = [''.join(i) for i in res]
    return res

print(random_strs(3, 5))
['GWX', 'KVW', 'DFX', 'FFM', 'QUY']
```

Thank you @larsks & @salparadise.